# Network is unreachable (HTTPS works fine, HTTP does't work)

Tags: networking, vmware, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a home network behind a microtik router (The most simple configuration). The computer connected to the router works stably and everything is OK. WSL with Ubuntu can't knock anywhere on http, but everything works over https.

There are several servers with vmware on which there are virtual machines with Ubuntu, http also does not work on them, but https works

WSL with Ubuntu

`$ curl https://google.com`

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

`$ curl http://google.com`

```
No response (Empty console)
```

Ubuntu over VMWare

`$ sudo apt update`

```
Err:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (213.180.204.183), connection timed out
Err:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
```

Comment: Firewall on mikrotik is empty. No drop rules

Comment: *"The computer connected to the router works stably and everything is OK."* - I assume this means that http works from Windows, but can you confirm by running `curl http://google.com` from PowerShell as well?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds 
My mistake. From Windows, http does not work either ... From the browser, from curl, etc.

Comment: No worries.  That's why we double-check these things! :-)  Do you want to close this out here and perhaps repost on [Super User](https://superuser.com)?

Comment: Yes, already do it) Thanks

Comment: Gm... How to close question?

Comment: Easiest just to delete it.  Since it has no answers, there's no "penalty" for deleting.  If you'd like to leave it here, but closed (perhaps to reference/link-to if you need to post on Super User), then you could "Flag" it and ask a moderator to close it.  Since you are the "owner" of the question, they shouldn't have a problem bypassing the normal "Close Vote" process, I don't believe.  (Mods - please correct me if Mr.Leo flags this, but I'm wrong on this.  Thanks!)  In the meantime, I'll flag it as well for "Close" (but not directly to a Mod).